# PDO "Invalid parameter number" invoking Pg stored procedure

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm wondering if this stored procedure is correct. I'm  trying to call this procedure in php which will put two bound varchar parameters through to the stored procedure. However I'm getting the error:

invalid parameter number :: name

where 'name' is one of the parameters I'm using.

What is the problem with my code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION treasurehunt.huntlogin(character varying, character varying)
 RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TreasureHunt.Player 
WHERE name=$1 AND password=$2$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION treasurehunt.huntlogin(character varying, character varying)
OWNER TO abro9592;
```

Here is the php

```
function checkLogin($name,$pass) {
// STUDENT TODO:
// Replace line below with code to validate details from the database
  $db = connect();
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM treasurehunt.huntlogin (:user,:pass)');
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    print "Error checking login: " . $e->getMessage(); 
    return FALSE;
}
return ($result==1);

}
```

Comment: That error is from php or postgres?

Comment: @NewK PHP, or PDO; that's not a PostgreSQL error message. See related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2105015/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11408037/398670

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q="invalid+parameter+number"+PDO

Comment: solved guys excellent job

Comment: Glad it's working now. Please add and accept an answer showing how you solved it, so this question is useful for future visitors.